# Dealing with SVN Renames for an file sync tool (like Dropbox)

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm working on a simple file sync tool for Windows that works like Dropbox but uses SVN. (I might open source it, it's just toy right not but it works really well.)

PROBLEM: Renaming a file... I can catch the event from the Windows OS with the old name and new name. But how can I register the rename in SVN without actually doing it in the file system?
I know SVN doesn't support that, but I want thinking of some other way. For example a rename is just a copy and a delete.

For example, I could do a server side copy but then the local copy is unversioned. There's got to be a way! Any ideas!?

[And deleting all the old files and reuploading them with new file names doesn't count ;) ]

Comment: Hmm.... What about: if the user renames oldname.txt to newname.txt, then: (1) copying the .svn folder into a new temp folder, (2) create an empty file oldname.txt, (3) run svn move, (4) copy back the .svn folder and commit... Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

See how [EasySVN](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/easysvn-tortoise/wiki) deals with it. It is an open source file sync tool for Windows & Mac OS X, with autocommit, based on Subversion.